# Python process hangs on 'join' at relatively higher concurrency

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am a beginner in Python, I tried to use multiprocessing to execute tasks in parallel, but I found that my main Process hangs on 'join' when the concurrency is a little bit higher, as like 3, and once the main process blocks, it can never recover

I found a similar problem, which answer is the logging will cause hanging, and I removed tha logging both in my main process and child process, but it didn't work. [Empty python process hangs on join [sys.stderr.flush()]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069717/empty-python-process-hangs-on-join-sys-stderr-flush)

My key code is shown below, my child process takes about 3s to execute.

I hope to get an answer. Thank you

```
        p = Process(name=driver_id, target=driver.run)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        return message.DriverResponse(status=message.SUCCESS, message='Driver execution Success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a mistake, it's nothing about Process.join.

There are three possible reasons:

1. python grpc + multiprocessing
2. python thread + multiprocessing
3. python threadpool + multiprocessing

When the concurrency reaches a certain level, a deadlock may be created. I will further search for root causes and solutions